# Trigger Background task in UWP

Tags: windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

My task is to execute the background task for every 25 minutes from the last launch time of the application. I used the time trigger to achieve this. But, when the user launches the application again after registering my background task I need to stop my background task from triggering. I tried with some System condition  and I am unable to get the solution.

Comment: un-register the background task in `OnLaunched` method. I'm not sure what "only user has to un-register the task"  mean.

Answer (score 0):

Every time, when you start your app, you could save current time stamp in local settings and [unregister](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br229869.aspx) the original background task.

After that, you can register it again.

Comment: No,only user has to un-register the task. In my end i want to restrict the task from triggering